# Remove string after second underscore with AWK

Tags: awk

I am trying to remove the string after the second underscore in the second column with AWK.

Here is my input data:

```
OTU10015    uncultured_Ascomycota_C31_F02_Lineage=Root  Fungi
OTU10071    Fusarium_sp._NRRL_52720_Lineage=Root    Fungi
OTU10082    Colletotrichum_dematium_BBA_62147_Lineage=Root  Fungi
```

The expected output is:

```
OTU10015    uncultured_Ascomycota   Fungi
OTU10071    Fusarium_sp.    Fungi
OTU10082    Colletotrichum_dematium   Fungi
```

I tried this code:

```
awk '{sub(/([^_]).*/,"",$2);print $1,$2,$3}' file1> file2
```

I found this code from another post and tried to modify it, 
but it will remove the entire second column.

How can I further modified the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps you want to remplace .* (matches anything) with [^\s]* (matches anything but space or tab)

Comment: https://regex101.com/ can be handy to test regex.  I find strange the regex you have here.

Comment: `^([^\s_]*_[^\s_]*).*` should do the job

Comment: `/^([^_ ]*_[^_ ]*).*/` should do the job to get the string you want to keep. `sub(/^([^_ ]*_[^_ ]*).*/, "\\1", $2)`  \\1 returns the first captured group in the regex

Comment: a captured group in regex is used to select text in the string. group 0 is the entire string match then groups are number in order of appearance of parenthesis.

Comment: `gensub(/^([^_ ]*_[^_ ]*).*/, "\\1", "g", $2)`

Comment: my mistake sorry ... you then need to use gensub

Comment: if you can't use captured groups in awk... i can't hep you... any how I hate awk, much prefer using perl that does the job easy peasy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regex based approach with `sub()` seems a wrong approach when you have a function like `split()` which can tackle the problem easily.

You just use the `split()` function to split on the `_` and use only the first two words. This is as minimal as you can get without disturbing the rest of the fields in the file.

```
awk '{ split($2, arr, "_"); $2=arr[1]"_"arr[2] }1' file
```

Printing the fields manually using `print` is rarely ever needed when you are modifying just one of the records. Doing a `{ .. }1` re-constructs the whole line based on the modifications based on any of the fields in the line. By virtue of modifying only `$2`, the whole line is reconstructed with the modification.